# UUID as primary key in DynamoDB -- good or bad idea?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

In a new DynamoDB table, my use cases are already fulfilled by the following key schema design:

- partition key: `user_id`
- sort key: `entity_id`

[image]

Basically, access patterns are:

1. Get specific post by a specific user.
2. Get specific comment by a specific user.
3. List all posts by specific user.
4. List all comments by specific user.
5. List all *entities* (post or comment) by a specific user.

What benefits do I get if I use a more random ID as partition key instead and simply use GSIs for my access patterns above?

- partition key: `pseudo_random_id` (This is going to be a UUID in reality. Please ignore that this is NOT a UUID in the illustration).
- GSI:

  - partition key: `user_id`
  - sort key: `entity_id`

[image]

Comment: FYI, your example `pseudo_random_id` values are *not* UUIDs. The term [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) has a very specific standardized meaning. A UUID is a 128-bit value, presented to humans in canonical format as 32 hex characters grouped by 4 hyphen characters. Example: `403fc3f4-9bb9-11e9-a2a3-2a2ae2dbcce4`. Please **edit the title and body of your Question** to make clear if you meant UUID or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need UUIDs or any pseudo-random ID.

It was once possible that you could have a hot partition if one user is particularly active, but hot partitions are [basically a non-issue](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/) now because of DynamoDB’s adaptive capacity. Furthermore, you should probably be limiting how fast users can create comments/posts, which would prevent hot partitions even if adaptive capacity didn’t exist.

(Why should you limit the rate a user can post? You don’t want a malicious actor to be able to create a new post every few milliseconds—you should have some sort of rate limit as a protection against denial of service attacks.)

Comment: Just adding a bit, he doesn't need it because he already has user ID, but UUIDs are great because you don't need to maintain an index, and since DynamoDB doesn't have an auto incremental feature you'd be needing to do extra queries and possibly getting into some very annoying Consistency issues.

Comment: @Mojimi, agreed. Any use cases where the type of ID isn’t already decided, it’s best to use a UUID.

Comment: @MatthewPope, stating that hot partitions are not an issue is misleading. It is true that provisioned throughput is now uniform instead of per partition, the way DynamoDB works is still that a hot partition will split and then re-split while all the cold partitions (servers) remain inactive.

Answer (score 1):

Using a UUID doesn't do anything for you...

It doesn't matter how random the partition key is.  All that matters is how many distinct partition keys you have and the volume/velocity of entries for that  partition key.

In other words, a unique value is a unique value.  Dynamo doesn't care if it's 16 bytes, 36 bytes or 128 bytes.

Dynamo applies it's own hash to the partition key to determine which partition the data will be placed into.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking at unique + sequence number in DynamoDB, worth to read [Atomic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html) Counters as a option. That maintains a counter in a table. But could be a problem for a high load application that requests IDs. Because the UpdateItem is a synchronized per tuple.