# DynamoDB basic questions regarding setup

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am planning to set up a database using DynamoDB

I have some general guidance questions:

1. What are some good habbits or styling that I should follow?
2. What is the difference between Querying and Scanning? Let's say I want to find an item that has attribute "Checked" == False, would it be considered as scanning or querying?
3. Is it good to set up UUID as partition Key? Would it affect querying and Scanning cost?
4. How do I use secondary Indices to assist with mentioned above search?
5. One of the general concept is using time triggered lambda to query DynamoDB and understand what actions need to be taken. Would this be a good set up? or would it be better to use DynamoDB Stream?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Gary -- welcome to Stack Overflow. The format of your post doesn't work well here. To get good results, focus your on one question at a time. And, try to be specific. For example, questions 2 and 3 are good questions. You can ask each one of those as separate questions though. And try the search feature: both of those have been answered here before (probably multiple times)

Comment: re #3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829651/uuid-as-primary-key-in-dynamodb-good-or-bad-idea?rq=1

Comment: re #2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452219/what-is-the-difference-between-scan-and-query-in-dynamodb-when-use-scan-query